# Django: add filtering sidebar to a change list admin view

Tags: python, django

I have a back-end module showing a quite long items listing that looks like this:

```
ID            Label            Type
1             Label 1          Type A
2             Label 2          Type B
3             Label 3          Type A
4             Label 4          Type D
5             Label 5          Type C
6             Label 6          Type D
7             Label 7          Type C
```

What I want to do is quite simple: I want to add a "filter by" sidebox listing all available types, for example

```
Available Types
Type A
Type B
Type C
Type D
```

If clicked they should enable filtering by single type. For example, if I click on "Type A" only items belonging to that type will be shown. Sidebar's HTML should look like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="?type=11">Type A</a></li>
<li><a href="?type=12">Type B</a></li>
<li><a href="?type=13">Type C</a></li>
<li><a href="?type=14">Type D</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I implement that? I'm quite confused right now...

Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `class based generic views`

```
from django.views import generic

class MyListView(generic.ListView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'my_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(MyListView, self).get_queryset()
        # get query value of query parameter 'type'
        type = self.request.GET.get('type', None)

        if type:
            # if type is given then filter
            return queryset.filter(type__exact=type)
        # if type is not give then return all
        return queryset
```

You can refer to docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)